# Unit Testing Nodejs Express applications

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mongoose, sinon

I'm trying to write a unit test for a controller that fetches a list of users from MongoDB using mongoose. Have written test for both success & error conditions. Is this correct & sufficient?

Or do I need to use supertest or superagent to test this controller using its route. But that is more of integration test, right. Here, I also run all my middlewares too.

```
// /controllers/users.js

exports.list = function (req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) return applib.handleError(res, err);
        res.json(users);    
    });
};


// test/users.js

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var sinon = require('sinon');
var users = require('../controllers/users');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var applib = require('../applib');

describe('User CRUD operations', function() {

  it('should list all users', function(done) {
    var fake = function(query, cb) {
      cb(null, [{ id: 1, email: 'foo@foobar.com' }]);
    };
    var stub = sinon.stub(User, 'find', fake);
    var req = {};
    var res = {
      json: function(data) {
        expect(data[0].id).to.equal(1);
        expect(data[0].email).to.equal('foo@foobar.com');
        done();
      }
    };
    users.list(req, res);
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('should err on user listing', function(done) {
    var fake = function(query, cb) {
      cb(new Error('Error'), null);
    };
    var stubUserFind = sinon.stub(User, 'find', fake);
    var stubHandleError = sinon.stub(applib, 'handleError');
    var req = {};
    var res = {};
    users.list(req, res);
    expect(stubHandleError.withArgs(res, new Error('Error')).calledOnce).to.be.true;
    stubUserFind.restore();
    stubHandleError.restore();
    done();
  });

});
```

Comment: For unit test, this is good enough. IMO, only in integration testing you need to test using route